# modeling a two variable

Tags: mathematical-modeling

I've been trying to find an elegant model for a function of two variables $(x,y)$ with the following constraints:

- $x \geq 0$
- $y \leq 0$
- $f(x,y) < 0$ when $x < 2$
- $f(x,y) < 0$ when $y \leq -2$
- $f(x,y) \geq 0$ when $x \geq 2$ and $y > -2$

It seems like I could use the hyperbolic paraboloid function as the starting point, but I haven't been able to figure out how to adjust the formula to get the function to come close to my constraints.

My intent is to use the resulting function to construct a feature for a machine learning algorithm, so it's not important that it's a hyperbolic paraboloid, just that it models the constraints well.

Comment: Posting all of your previous work would make this a much easier thing to help with.

Comment: It's not going to be continuous, because $f^{-1}([0,\infty))$ isn't open